# Explanation of Search Function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to right a short explanation for this code that i have involved in my website to search the first column in a table.
Can anyone help me with this?
I am unsure if this is against the rules for stackoverflow, but giving it a shot.
(the code works fine)

```js
function tableSearch(){
    let input, filter, table, tr, td, h, txtValue;

    //Initializing Var
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for(let h = 0; h < tr.length; h++){
        td = tr[h].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if(td){
            txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if(txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1){
                tr[h].style.display = "";
            }
            else {
                tr[h].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What **exactly** are you searching for? Anything not working with the given code?

Comment: `Hides all table rows in which the first cell's textContent doesn't match the input (case-insensitive)`.

Comment: No i mentioned that the code works fine, just need a breif explanation of it really. The code will search in the first column of a HTML table.

Comment: @connexo - the `tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");` - it is my understanding it will find all the rows across all the tables in the given `document`, is that correct? Or, may be it only picks-up the ones corresponding to `table` (which is assigned like so: `table = document.getElementById("myTable");`.

Comment: `tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");` should be `tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");` in your code, otherwise it will affect all `tr` elements in all `table`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
function tableSearch(){
    let input, filter, table, tr, td, h, txtValue;

    //Initializing Var
    input = document.getElementById("myInput"); //find input element
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase(); //the search value in user's search input
    table = document.getElementById("myTable"); //don't see anywhere using this variable
    tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr"); //get all `tr` (maybe from your table?)

    //loop through all `tr`
    for(let h = 0; h < tr.length; h++){
        //get only first `td` from the current `tr` (`tr` is based on index)
        td = tr[h].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        //if found the first `td`
        if(td){

            //get the first `td` content
            txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
 
            //if the first `td` content matches with your search input
            //show the entire current `tr`
            if(txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1){
                tr[h].style.display = "";
            }
            //if the first `td` content does not with your search input
            //hide the entire current `tr`
            else {
                tr[h].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One side note here that `toUpperCase()` on search input value and `td` content is to ignore case sensitive